# How to define Android intent filter to consume doi urls

Tags: android, intentfilter

My current Android application has a use case for consuming/processing DOI urls.

I am attempting to define an intent filter to support users sharing a doi url with the following intent filter

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https://doi.org/" />
            <data android:scheme="http://doi.org/" />

        </intent-filter>
```

however when i attempt to share a doi url my application is not listed it the possible candidate applications.

is it possible to achieve the desired result with intent filters.

one thing i am confused about is when to use action `VIEW` or `SEND`